# Where is the memory leak in my C++ code and how can I fix it

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, sfml

I'm a getting memory leak when I load a new level in my game.

Each time I call the LoadMap() function my ram jumps a little higher until the program crashes with errors like:

Unhandled exception at 0x752dc42d in TileGame.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x003af420..

or...

Unhandled exception at 0x7787a30e in TileGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefef6.

I'm using 2d vectors like these:

```
//A 2D array of Tile pointers
std::vector<std::vector<Tile*>> map;

//A 2D array of Tile pointers for the background
std::vector<std::vector<Tile*>> background_map;
```

Here is the NewLevel() function which clears both of my maps that store the tiles for the game. The function also calls the LoadMap() function.

```
void Level::NewLevel(std::string filename){
    //Generate a new level with Island generator.   
    //IslandGenerator* island = new IslandGenerator();
    this->map.clear();
    this->background_map.clear();

    sf::Image size_image;

    if (!size_image.loadFromFile("data/Levels/" + filename)){
        std::cout << "failed to load image" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    SetDimensions(size_image.getSize().x, size_image.getSize().y);

    LoadMap(filename);
}
```

This is the function I use to resize my maps each time I load my tiles:

```
void Level::SetDimensions(int w, int h)
{
    this->map.resize(w);
    this->background_map.resize(w);

    //Each row has h columns of null Tile pointers
    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        this->map.at(i).resize(h, 0);
        this->background_map.at(i).resize(h,0);
    }

}
```

Finally, this is the LoadMap() function which loads all the tiles from an image and sets their textures and attributes.

```
void Level::LoadMap(std::string filename)
{

    // Loads as image to to use the .getSize() operation not allowed for textures
    if (!Image_load.loadFromFile("data/Levels/" + filename))
        std::cout << "failed to load image" << std::endl;

    if (!background_image_load.loadFromFile("data/Levels/background_" + filename))
        std::cout << "failed to load image" << std::endl;

    x_load = Image_load.getSize().x;
    y_load = Image_load.getSize().y;

    this->level_w = x_load;
    this->level_h = y_load;

    player = new Player(entity_texture_manager);

    AddEntity((this->screen_size_x/2)-(player->baseSprite.getLocalBounds().width/2), (this->screen_size_y/2)-(player->baseSprite.getLocalBounds().height/2), player);

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Tile* new_tile = new Tile();
    Tile* new_background_tile = new Tile();

    for(int ii = 0; ii < y_load; ii++)
    {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < x_load; jj++)
        {

            try
            {
                new_tile = new Tile();
                new_background_tile = new Tile();
            }
            catch (std::bad_alloc& ba)
            {
                std::cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << '\n';
                return;
            }


            //new_tile = new Tile();
            //new_background_tile = new Tile();

            color_load = Image_load.getPixel (jj, ii);

            // Get the background pixels
            background_color_load = background_image_load.getPixel(jj,ii);


            // Background-----------------------------------------
            if((int)background_color_load.r == 128 && (int)background_color_load.g == 0){
                new_background_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(11));
                new_background_tile->color = 11;
                new_background_tile->type = 0;
                new_background_tile->light_blocking_amount = 20;
            }
            else
            {
                new_background_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(2));
                new_background_tile->color = 2;
                new_background_tile->type = 0;
                new_background_tile->light_blocking_amount = 20;
            }
            // ---------------------------------------------------

            if((int)color_load.r == 255 && (int)color_load.g == 255){
                new_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(3));
                new_tile->color = 3;
                new_tile->type = 1;
            }

            //grass1
            else if((int)color_load.r == 0 && (int)color_load.g == 128 && (int)color_load.b == 128){
            new_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(10));
            new_tile->color = 10;
            new_tile->type = 0;
            }

            else if((int)color_load.r == 0 && (int)color_load.g == 128 && (int)color_load.b == 255){
            new_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(12));
            new_tile->color = 12;
            new_tile->type = 0;
            }

            else if((int)color_load.r == 0 && (int)color_load.g == 100 && (int)color_load.b == 128){
            new_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(13));
            new_tile->color = 13;
            new_tile->type = 0;
            }

            else if((int)color_load.r == 255){
            new_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(1));
            new_tile->color = 1;
            new_tile->type = 1;
            }

            else if((int)color_load.g == 255){
            new_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(0));
            new_tile->color = 0;
            new_tile->type = 1;
            }

            else if((int)color_load.b == 255){
            new_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(2));
            new_tile->color = 2;
            new_tile->type = 0;
            }

            // brick
            else if((int)color_load.g == 128 && (int)color_load.b == 128 && (int)color_load.r == 128){
            new_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(9));
            new_tile->color = 9;
            new_tile->type = 1;
            }
            // sand
            else if((int)color_load.r == 128){
            new_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(7));
            new_tile->color = 7;
            new_tile->type = 1;
            }
            else if((int)color_load.g == 128){
            new_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(8));
            new_tile->color = 8;
            new_tile->type = 1;
            }
            else{
            new_tile->setTexture(texture_manager.getTexture(0));
            new_tile->color = 0;
            new_tile->type = 1;
            }

            //Adds the specified tile to the 2D array

            //cout << map.size() << endl;

            map[jj][ii] = 0;
            background_map[jj][ii] = 0;

            AddTile(jj, ii, new_tile);

            AddBackgroundTile(jj, ii, new_background_tile);

            /*
            //------Ouput Method---------

            for (int r=0; r < map.size(); r++)
            {
                for (int c=0; c < map[r].size(); c++)
                    cout << map[r][c] << '/t';
                cout << endl;
            }

            */

        }


    }   



}
```

**Update:**

Thanks for the comments. I added a function to delete my Tile objects but this still seems to do nothing.

I now call this function.

```
void Level::CleanUp(){


    for(int ii = 0; ii < this->map.size(); ii++){
        for(int jj = 0; jj < this->h; jj++){

            delete &this->map[ii][jj];
            delete &this->background_map[ii][jj];

        }
    }


    this->map.clear();
    this->background_map.clear();

}
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

**Update 2:**

Here is my tile class:

```
class Tile
{

public:
    int type;
    int color;
    int light_level;
    int light_blocking_amount;
    int loc_x, loc_y;

    int LightRadius;
    int LightLevel;

    Tile();
    ~Tile();

    sf::Sprite baseSprite;

    void Draw(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow* rw);

    void setTexture(sf::Texture& texture);
};
```

**Update 3:**

The sprite class is a built in sfml class:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// SFML - Simple and Fast Multimedia Library
// Copyright (C) 2007-2014 Laurent Gomila (laurent.gom@gmail.com)
//
// This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or implied warranty.
// In no event will the authors be held liable for any damages arising from the use of this software.
//
// Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
// including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute it freely,
// subject to the following restrictions:
//
// 1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented;
// you must not claim that you wrote the original software.
// If you use this software in a product, an acknowledgment
// in the product documentation would be appreciated but is not required.
//
// 2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such,
// and must not be misrepresented as being the original software.
//
// 3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef SFML_SPRITE_HPP
#define SFML_SPRITE_HPP

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Headers
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <SFML/Graphics/Export.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Drawable.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Transformable.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Vertex.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Rect.hpp>


namespace sf
{
class Texture;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \brief Drawable representation of a texture, with its
/// own transformations, color, etc.
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class SFML_GRAPHICS_API Sprite : public Drawable, public Transformable
{
public :

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Default constructor
    ///
    /// Creates an empty sprite with no source texture.
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Sprite();

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Construct the sprite from a source texture
    ///
    /// \param texture Source texture
    ///
    /// \see setTexture
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    explicit Sprite(const Texture& texture);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Construct the sprite from a sub-rectangle of a source texture
    ///
    /// \param texture Source texture
    /// \param rectangle Sub-rectangle of the texture to assign to the sprite
    ///
    /// \see setTexture, setTextureRect
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Sprite(const Texture& texture, const IntRect& rectangle);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Change the source texture of the sprite
    ///
    /// The \a texture argument refers to a texture that must
    /// exist as long as the sprite uses it. Indeed, the sprite
    /// doesn't store its own copy of the texture, but rather keeps
    /// a pointer to the one that you passed to this function.
    /// If the source texture is destroyed and the sprite tries to
    /// use it, the behaviour is undefined.
    /// If \a resetRect is true, the TextureRect property of
    /// the sprite is automatically adjusted to the size of the new
    /// texture. If it is false, the texture rect is left unchanged.
    ///
    /// \param texture New texture
    /// \param resetRect Should the texture rect be reset to the size of the new texture?
    ///
    /// \see getTexture, setTextureRect
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void setTexture(const Texture& texture, bool resetRect = false);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Set the sub-rectangle of the texture that the sprite will display
    ///
    /// The texture rect is useful when you don't want to display
    /// the whole texture, but rather a part of it.
    /// By default, the texture rect covers the entire texture.
    ///
    /// \param rectangle Rectangle defining the region of the texture to display
    ///
    /// \see getTextureRect, setTexture
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void setTextureRect(const IntRect& rectangle);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Set the global color of the sprite
    ///
    /// This color is modulated (multiplied) with the sprite's
    /// texture. It can be used to colorize the sprite, or change
    /// its global opacity.
    /// By default, the sprite's color is opaque white.
    ///
    /// \param color New color of the sprite
    ///
    /// \see getColor
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void setColor(const Color& color);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Get the source texture of the sprite
    ///
    /// If the sprite has no source texture, a NULL pointer is returned.
    /// The returned pointer is const, which means that you can't
    /// modify the texture when you retrieve it with this function.
    ///
    /// \return Pointer to the sprite's texture
    ///
    /// \see setTexture
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    const Texture* getTexture() const;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Get the sub-rectangle of the texture displayed by the sprite
    ///
    /// \return Texture rectangle of the sprite
    ///
    /// \see setTextureRect
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    const IntRect& getTextureRect() const;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Get the global color of the sprite
    ///
    /// \return Global color of the sprite
    ///
    /// \see setColor
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    const Color& getColor() const;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Get the local bounding rectangle of the entity
    ///
    /// The returned rectangle is in local coordinates, which means
    /// that it ignores the transformations (translation, rotation,
    /// scale, ...) that are applied to the entity.
    /// In other words, this function returns the bounds of the
    /// entity in the entity's coordinate system.
    ///
    /// \return Local bounding rectangle of the entity
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    FloatRect getLocalBounds() const;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Get the global bounding rectangle of the entity
    ///
    /// The returned rectangle is in global coordinates, which means
    /// that it takes in account the transformations (translation,
    /// rotation, scale, ...) that are applied to the entity.
    /// In other words, this function returns the bounds of the
    /// sprite in the global 2D world's coordinate system.
    ///
    /// \return Global bounding rectangle of the entity
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    FloatRect getGlobalBounds() const;

private :

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Draw the sprite to a render target
    ///
    /// \param target Render target to draw to
    /// \param states Current render states
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    virtual void draw(RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states) const;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Update the vertices' positions
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void updatePositions();

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// \brief Update the vertices' texture coordinates
    ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void updateTexCoords();

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Member data
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Vertex m_vertices[4]; ///< Vertices defining the sprite's geometry
    const Texture* m_texture; ///< Texture of the sprite
    IntRect m_textureRect; ///< Rectangle defining the area of the source texture to display
};

} // namespace sf


#endif // SFML_SPRITE_HPP


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \class sf::Sprite
/// \ingroup graphics
///
/// sf::Sprite is a drawable class that allows to easily display
/// a texture (or a part of it) on a render target.
///
/// It inherits all the functions from sf::Transformable:
/// position, rotation, scale, origin. It also adds sprite-specific
/// properties such as the texture to use, the part of it to display,
/// and some convenience functions to change the overall color of the
/// sprite, or to get its bounding rectangle.
///
/// sf::Sprite works in combination with the sf::Texture class, which
/// loads and provides the pixel data of a given texture.
///
/// The separation of sf::Sprite and sf::Texture allows more flexibility
/// and better performances: indeed a sf::Texture is a heavy resource,
/// and any operation on it is slow (often too slow for real-time
/// applications). On the other side, a sf::Sprite is a lightweight
/// object which can use the pixel data of a sf::Texture and draw
/// it with its own transformation/color/blending attributes.
///
/// It is important to note that the sf::Sprite instance doesn't
/// copy the texture that it uses, it only keeps a reference to it.
/// Thus, a sf::Texture must not be destroyed while it is
/// used by a sf::Sprite (i.e. never write a function that
/// uses a local sf::Texture instance for creating a sprite).
///
/// See also the note on coordinates and undistorted rendering in sf::Transformable.
///
/// Usage example:
/// \code
/// // Declare and load a texture
/// sf::Texture texture;
/// texture.loadFromFile("texture.png");
///
/// // Create a sprite
/// sf::Sprite sprite;
/// sprite.setTexture(texture);
/// sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(10, 10, 50, 30));
/// sprite.setColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 200));
/// sprite.setPosition(100, 25);
///
/// // Draw it
/// window.draw(sprite);
/// \endcode
///
/// \see sf::Texture, sf::Transformable
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: are you deleting every instance of objects that you created with "new" when you've finished using them? That's pretty much how memory leaks are created... if you have a vector of pointers to objects, you must delete ALL those objects before you clear the vector. Or use smart pointers

Comment: Where is the delete call for the memory allocated? map.clear() wont clear the dynamically allcated objects.

Comment: So if I have like this->map[ii][jj]->sprite; I would need to delete the sprite from memory?

Comment: It just occurred to me that the wording of my comment might be unclear... It should read "failing to do that is pretty much how memory leaks are created..." What that means is you *must* call delete on any object that was created with new once you've finished with it. If you place pointers to "newed" Objects in a data structure and don't have other copies of the pointers, you must delete all those objects before clearing the data structure. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the replys, please look at the update to my question.

Comment: The fastest way to get rid of memory leaks is to not introduce them.  That can be done by using objects, `vector<Tile>` instead of `vector<Tile*>`, or using vectors of smart pointer, i.e. `<vector<shared_ptr<Tile>>>`.  In this day and age of C++, rarely do you ever need to use naked calls to `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Also please post your `Tile` class.  This way we get a better picture of exactly the data you're creating dynamically, and even if it's worth using pointers.

Comment: Note you have two redundant new Tile() calls when you declare the variable new_tile and new_background_tile before your initilization loop, and these objects never get deleted even with your new code.

Comment: @user106342 - Another thing -- don't name variables the same as standard classes.  For example, your usage of `map`.  There already is a `std::map` class in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I posted my tile class.

Comment: @user106342 - I mean the `Tile` class itself, not the implementation.

Comment: I think I'll try changing my code not to use the pointers for the tile class like you suggested.

Comment: ah ok, I changed it to the tile class.

Comment: @user106342 - ok, the only outstanding issue is `Sprite`, so you need to post the `Sprite` class (no need to see the implementation).  The goal is to see if you can safely use Tile objects as-is without any issues.

Comment: I added the sprite class. It is built in class that comes with the SFML API I use.

Comment: Another question though, if I switched over to std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> map; instead of using pointers would that slow my code down?

Comment: @user106342 - See my answer.  It uses shared_ptr in a more localized manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you've posted, my suggestion would be to change your Tile class this way to possibly alleviate the memory leak:

```
#include <memory>
class Tile
{
    public:
        int type;
        int color;
        int light_level;
        int light_blocking_amount;
        int loc_x, loc_y;

        int LightRadius;
        int LightLevel;
        std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite> baseSprite;

        Tile();
        //... other member functions
        //
    };
```

The `Sprite` class is a little complex, and I don't know if it's copyable as-is (you can write a small test app to see if Sprite's are [safely] copyable).  Therefore to play it safe, create it as a smart pointer, and instantiate it on the constructor of `Tile`.

Then I would use this:

```
std::vector<Tile>
```

Instead of

```
std::vector<Tile*>
```

When a Tile is constructed, you are constructing a new Sprite object:

```
Tile::Tile() : baseSprite(new sf::Sprite) 
{
   // whatever else
}
```

Now the Tile class can be used as an object.  The caveat is to make sure that you don't have cycles within the shared_ptr (read up on shared_ptr usage and cycles).  But from the code you posted, I don't think there will be, but you should check anyway.

Once you do this, the `Tile` destructor will no longer be needed, since the shared_ptr will delete when the last reference to it is deleted.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the help! As I have a ton of code it will take me a little to make it so it doesn't use pointers. However, once I get that and the tile class changed I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: So I think finally got this solution mostly implemented. While I still use pointers to access the tiles in my get function and some other places, I now use a 2d vector without pointers and also have implemented the shared pointer for sprites. However, the tiles are now loaded much much slower and the memory leak still seems to be there. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: 1) For slowness, make sure you're running an optimized (release) build, not an unoptimized (or "debug") build.  2) If you're calling `new` outside of the smart pointers, the potential for memory leak is still there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't delete your old Tile objects. They are defined as pointers so you will need to manually delete them before you clear your background_map and map.

Actually, I don't see any delete statements at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please look at the update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop at `1` you have memory leak immediately, as the memory allocated at `0` are not deleted.

```
Tile* new_tile = new Tile(); // <-- 0
Tile* new_background_tile = new Tile(); // <-- 0

for(int ii = 0; ii < y_load; ii++)
{
    for(int jj = 0; jj < x_load; jj++)
    {
        try
        {
            new_tile = new Tile();  // <--- 1
            new_background_tile = new Tile(); // <--- 1
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added delete new_tile; delete new_background_tile; after the for loops finish to fix that memory leak. But their is still a much larger memory leak that is present.

Comment: Adding `delete` after the loops doesn't fix memory leak in this case, you don't need to allocate memory at `0` at all.

Comment: Makes sense, changed them to Tile* new_tile;
 Tile* new_background_tile; However, I still seem to be getting a memory leak somewhere. :/